# How to stop window.scroll() after specific event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullscreen

I want to make the sticky-nav to act similar(scroll is off when the menu is expanded) to this website's nav(http://amandagerhardsen.com/#cloudbusting/4) when expanded.

How do I do it?

```
 var Boxlayout = (function () {
        var $el = $('#sticky-nav'),
            $sections = $el.children('section'),
            // work panels
            $workPanelsContainer = $('#bl-panel-work-items'),
            // close work panel trigger
            $closeWorkItem = $workPanelsContainer.find('nav > span.hidemenu'),
            transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
                'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition': 'transitionend'
            },
            // transition end event name
            transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
            // support css transitions
            supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

        function init() {
            initEvents();
        }

        function initEvents() {
            $sections.each(function () {
                var $section = $(this);
                // expand the clicked section and scale down the others
                $section.on('click', function () {
                    if (!$section.data('open')) {
                        $section.data('open', true).addClass('bl-expand bl-expand-top');
                        $el.addClass('bl-expand-item');
                    }
                }).find('span.hidemenu').on('click', function () {
                    // close the expanded section and scale up the others
                    $section.data('open', false).removeClass('bl-expand').on(transEndEventName, function (event) {
                        if (!$(event.target).is('section')) return false;
                        $(this).off(transEndEventName).removeClass('bl-expand-top');
                    });
                    if (!supportTransitions) {
                        $section.removeClass('bl-expand-top');
                    }
                    $el.removeClass('bl-expand-item');
                    return false;
                });
            });
            // clicking on a work item: the current section scales down and the respective work panel slides up
            $workItems.on('click', function (event) {
                // scale down main section
                $sectionWork.addClass('bl-scale-down');
                // show panel for this work item
                $workPanelsContainer.addClass('bl-panel-items-show');
                var $panel = $workPanelsContainer.find("[data-panel='" + $(this).data('panel') + "']");
                currentWorkPanel = $panel.index();
                $panel.addClass('bl-show-work');
                return false;
            });
            // navigating the work items: current work panel scales down and the next work panel slides up
            $nextWorkItem.on('click', function (event) {
                if (isAnimating) {
                    return false;
                }
                isAnimating = true;
                var $currentPanel = $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel);
                currentWorkPanel = currentWorkPanel < totalWorkPanels - 1 ? currentWorkPanel + 1 : 0;
                var $nextPanel = $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel);
                $currentPanel.removeClass('bl-show-work').addClass('bl-hide-current-work').on(transEndEventName, function (event) {
                    if (!$(event.target).is('div')) return false;
                    $(this).off(transEndEventName).removeClass('bl-hide-current-work');
                    isAnimating = false;
                });
                if (!supportTransitions) {
                    $currentPanel.removeClass('bl-hide-current-work');
                    isAnimating = false;
                }
                $nextPanel.addClass('bl-show-work');
                return false;
            });
            // clicking the work panels close button: the current work panel slides down and the section scales up again
            $closeWorkItem.on('click', function (event) {
                // scale up main section
                $sectionWork.removeClass('bl-scale-down');
                $workPanelsContainer.removeClass('bl-panel-items-show');
                $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel).removeClass('bl-show-work');
                return false;
            });
        }
        return {
            init: init
        };
    })();
```

Comment: Scroll still works when menu is expanded?? Do you mean dont scroll the page when hovering over menu?

Comment: I already have css animation.  What I want is when you click on the menu icon on that site it expands.Then if you scroll down it doesn't work unless you collapse the menu. I want to disable the scroll like that.

Comment: If you expand the menu you can **still scroll the page** if you try and scroll outside of the menu (with mouse over pink bit I can scroll still) - if you try and scroll while hovering over the menu the page does not scroll - this is the ideal behaviour (as that site does already) - NEVER stop a user using the mousewheel to scroll or side bars - it is a recipe for disaster and frustration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77P2e/

Be careful to unlock scrolling again when done, or this could be very annoying for the user!

**Setup code**

```
var $window = $(window), previousScrollTop = 0, scrollLock = false;

$window.scroll(function(event) {     
    if(scrollLock) {
        $window.scrollTop(previousScrollTop); 
    }

    previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

});
```

**To lock scroll position:**

```
scrollLock = true;
```

**And to unlock again...**

```
scrollLock = false;
```

As an example use, you could lock the window scroll position when the mouse enters the navigation area, and unlock it again when the mouse leaves:

```
$("nav")
    .mouseenter(function(){ scrollLock = true; })
    .mouseleave(function(){ scrollLock = false; });
```

Comment: @JoshHarrison Clean and efficient solution. Kudos.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the accepted answer is not what should be achieved, as the `window.scroll()` function will be still running (endlessly), even if the 'event' has occured.

The `window.scroll()` function is an event handler. So use `on()` to bind the event and `off()` to unbind it (after the 'event' has occured).

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { // bind event handler
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log("page Y-Offset: ", offset); // just to see it working
    if(offset >= 100) $(window).off('scroll'); // unbind the event handler when the condition is met

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The Javascript solution is a little janky for me, on mobile. It's like it scrolls a little bit and then snaps back into place.

However, I figured out a way to do it much more cleanly, without any jank, just by changing CSS's `overflow` property on the part you don't want to scroll. Here's the code in d3 but the concept should be pretty clear:

```
var body = d3.select('body');

var preventScroll = function () {
        body.style('overflow', 'hidden');
    },
    allowScroll = function () {
        body.style('overflow', 'scroll');
    };

d3.select('#sticky-nav')
  .on('touchmove', preventScroll)
  .on('touchstart', preventScroll)
  .on('touchend', allowScroll)
  .on('touchcancel', allowScroll);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was using jquery animation,

`if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.btn').offset().top + $('.btn').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight)
{
$(".tab").stop();
}`

I did this and it worked.

.btn is the button. That .tab div would stop if it scrolls to that position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery animation you can try using the `stop()` function on the animated object.